# How does the air-circulation in the lower stratosphere look like?

Tags: meteorology, wind, open-data, stratosphere, simulation

I would like to simulate the trajectory of a weather balloon in an altitude of 12 to 20 km.
For this I would like to know how the velocity-field (i.e. wind-speed and direction as a function of position and time) looks like and how constant it is in the time and space domain.

Is there some publicly available data about air-circulation in the stratosphere? Or do you have an idea how to generate test-data for my simulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This presentation](http://www.goes-r.gov/downloads/AMS/AMS2015/January%208/Joint%20Session%2019/Cubesat%20FTS%20for%203D%20Winds%20AMS%20J19.4.pdf) mentions "Atmospheric Motion Vectors (AMVs)", and specifically mentions a number of AMVs, which separately cover the globe (GOES AMVs ±60N, plus polar AMVs from MODIS/AVHRR/VIIRS, and a combined product from UW CIMSS) but says that are all only 3 layers. That presentation is talking about producing a more global, higher resolution product, but it's only a year old, so I'd guess the data isn't available yet.

However, the [UW CIMSS AMV page](http://tropic.ssec.wisc.edu/misc/winds/info.winds.gridded.html) says that their datasets have 13 layers, so maybe it is suited for what you need. The data is gap-filled with modelled data.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found these maps: http://earth.nullschool.net/

It is a nice visualization of winds at different elevations (from surface up to 10hPa).